# why is WSDL client not working on Windows

Tags: java, wsdl, webservice-client

I have a `WSDL` project I have been working on. The project was working just fine on both `Linux` and `windows` until I upgraded from `Java 8` to `openJDK 11`. On Linux it still working, the problem is on Windows. I cannot get the `WSDL` studs to even initialize, it is like the program completely comes to a stand still once it reaches the part where it is suppose to initialize and call the `WSDL studs`, below is my `WSDL` definition

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.1-b01-. --><!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.1-b01-. -->
    <definitions
            xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"
            xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.asycuda.org"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
            targetNamespace="http://www.asycuda.org" name="MyWbService">
        <types>
            <xsd:schema>
                <xsd:import namespace="http://www.asycuda.org"
                            schemaLocation="http://ip:port/asyws/WsItem?xsd=1"/>
            </xsd:schema>
        </types>
        <message name="wsItemStore">
            <part name="parameters" element="tns:wsItemStore"/>
        </message>
        <message name="wsItemStoreResponse">
            <part name="parameters" element="tns:wsItemStoreResponse"/>
        </message>
        <portType name="WsItem">
            <operation name="wsItemStore">
                <input wsam:Action="urn:wsItemStore" message="tns:wsItemStore"/>
                <output wsam:Action="http://www.asycuda.org/WsItem/wsItemStoreResponse" message="tns:wsItemStoreResponse"/>
            </operation>
        </portType>
        <binding name="WsItemServicePortBinding" type="tns:WsItem">
            <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
            <operation name="wsItemStore">
                <soap:operation soapAction="urn:wsItemStore"/>
                <input>
                    <soap:body use="literal"/>
                </input>
                <output>
                    <soap:body use="literal"/>
                </output>
            </operation>
        </binding>
        <service name="WsItemService">
            <port name="WsItemServicePort" binding="tns:WsItemServicePortBinding">
                <soap:address location="http://ip:port/asyws/WsItem"/>
            </port>
        </service>
    </definitions>
```

And how I access it from `Java`

```
try{
        logger.debug("Initialization started");
        org.asycuda.WsItemService service = new org.asycuda.WsItemService();
        org.asycuda.WsItem port = service.getWsItemServicePort();
        Authenticator.setDefault(new WSAuthenticator(username, password));
        logger.debug("Initialization complete");
       }catch(Exception e){
         logger.error(e);
     }
```

When I run this code in Windows, the program simply stops at the `logger.debug("Initialization started")` message, on the other hand, when I run it in Linux, the initialization goes through. How can I fix this?

Comment: You almost certainly need to configure [modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html). Java 9 added modularity to Java. So either configure the modules, or down-grade to Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was missing a few dependencies. When running the app on `Linux` I was running it in `intellij` but to run it on windows I would compile a jar from my IDE. The IDE was injecting missing dependencies at run time so is the reason it was working fine on Linux but not on windows.

I had to add these dependencies to get it to work correctly with `Java 11`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```